# How to plot a Poisson process with an exponential kernel

Tags: python, math, matplotlib, scipy, statsmodels

I would like to simulate times from a Poisson process with an exponential kernel in a given time window. I have the following code which works but is horrible.

```
# Attempt to simulate a Poisson process.
import random
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
t = 0
rate = 5
timeinterval = 100
t = int(100*random.expovariate(rate))
times=[]
while (t < timeinterval):
    times.append(t)
    print t
    t+= int(100*random.expovariate(rate))

print times
s = [0]*100
a=0.5
for i in xrange(len(s)):
    s[i] = int(i-1 in times) + (1-a) * s[i-1]
plt.plot(s)
plt.show()
```

How can I avoid the kludges in this code?

For example, I multiply by 100 and use int just so I can plot the data. Ideally I would not do that.

On a related note, I want the time interval to be 1 not 100 (having got rid of all the *100 parts of the code) but I then couldn't see how to plot the result.

[image]

Comment: why do you plot the decay? You could use vlines at the specific times t. Then there is also no reason to convert times to an integer grid.

Comment: @user333700 I would like to visualise the delay. Ultimately I will be adding other things to the diagram as well and see how they intersect with the delay.

Comment: If you need the delay, then it is easiest to work on a grid of time points. However, you can use any regularly spaced grid instead of an integer grid. For example, if you round `times` to 2 decimals, then you could build a grid of 100 time points in the unit interval, 0, 0.01, ..., 1.

Answer (score 2):

The main reason for the kludges is you solve the problem by sampling the times of the spikes, but then you want to force them on a grid, since you want them to decay.

So instead I propose to start off with a grid and compute the probability that a spike occurs. Then you can decay the signal at the same time:

```
import random
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from numpy import linspace, exp

random.seed(123)
t0 = 0
t1 = 1
times = linspace(t0, t1, 1000)
dt = times[1] - times[0]
result = []
s = 0
decay = 0.01  # decay to 1/e after this time                                                       
lambd = 0.2   # expect roughly one spike each timeinterval lambd                                   
n = 0
for t in times:
    if random.random() > exp(-dt/lambd): # actually random.random() < 1 - exp(-dt/lambd)           
        s += 1.0
        n += 1
    s = s * exp(-dt/decay)
    result.append(s)

print "number of observed spikes=%i expected mean=%f" % (n, (t1-t0)/lambd)
plt.figure(figsize=(6,4))
plt.plot(times, result)
plt.savefig("process.png")
plt.show()
```

Here is a sample output for the seed `123`: [image: example result]

Note that you get similar (not the same due to the random process) results regardless of the resolution `dt` by changing the last argument in `linspace`, just as it should be.

Edit: you can also do this using `expovariate`, which is closer to your original approach.

```
rate = 1.0/lambd
tspike = t0 + random.expovariate(rate)
for t in times:
    s = s * exp(-dt/decay)
    if t > tspike:
        s += 1.0
        n += 1
        tspike = t + random.expovariate(rate)
    result.append(s)
```

Here I also swapped decay and spike generation, so they start at `1`.